# How to use NPOI to read Excel spreadsheet that contains empty cells?

Tags: c#, excel, npoi

When I read Excel worksheet using NPOI, empty cells are skipped. For example, it the row contains `A, B, , C` and I read it using

```
IRow row = sheet.GetRow(rowNb)
```

then `row.Cells[1].ToString()` will output `B` (as expected) but `row.Cells[2].ToString()` will output `C` instead of an empty string. Is there a way to keep empty cells? Thanks.

Comment: It would help to update your post with the code you use to read the Excel file.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Try the `GetCell` method with the `MissingCellPolicy`:

```
ICell cell = row.GetCell(2, MissingCellPolicy.RETURN_NULL_AND_BLANK);
```

Answer (score 3):

In completion to the accepted answer, the policy can be set on the workbook level as well

```cs
workbook.MissingCellPolicy = MissingCellPolicy.RETURN_NULL_AND_BLANK;
```

This way the policy is applied implicitly when you call `GetCell`, no need to pass it every time as a parameter

```cs
ICell cell = row.GetCell(2);
```

Note that (at least in the version I'm using) if you do `row.Cells[index]`, it ignores the policy so it only works if you call `row.GetCell(index)`

Comment: Also as a complement, the `MissingCellPolicy.RETURN_NULL_AND_BLANK` makes the return of `row.GetCell()` be null when the cell is null. If you want it to return an empty string, use the `MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK` policy.